Delphi Firemonkey - Simple FlyOut Menu on Android
I'm using a regular MultiView control for the menu of my app (primary Android). But I also want to have a kind of context menu that drops down when a user taps the menu button in the upper right corner. Examples:

Firefoy Android App - 3 dots open the menu on the right side
WhatsApp Android App - 3 dots open the menu to create a new group or open settings

Things I've tried without success:

regular Delphi PopUp Menu - not usable on Android
TListBox with linked animation that appears when the button is pressed, works but not as an overlay, UI is moved down or beside, not what the user expects. Tested some combinations of the Align property of the Listbox (Right, None) and also of the TabControl (CLient, Contents).
TPanel, with animation, nearly the same as TListBox, simply no Z-order

Styling is nice, but not so important. Pretty sure there is a simple solution, but I could not get it done. I'm using Delphi 12.2, testing Android phones are Samsung with Android 13, 14.
// OnClick handler for the 3-dot button
// works, but moves all controls on my TTabControl to the left :-(
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListBoxMenu.Visible := not ListBoxMenu.Visible;
if ListBoxMenu.Visible then
   begin
   ListBoxMenu.ApplyStyleLookup;
   ListBoxMenu.RealignContent;
   end;
end;

// head of .fmx file
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ToolBar1: TToolBar
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 46.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
      Align = Right
      Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 589.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 46.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 46.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'detailstoolbutton'
      Text = 'SpeedButton1'
      OnClick = SpeedButton1Click
    end
  end
  object ListboxMenu: TListBox
    Align = Right // also tried None
    Margins.Right = 30.000000000000000000
    Position.X = 528.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 49.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 107.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 144.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    Visible = False
    DisableFocusEffect = True
    DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
    Viewport.Width = 103.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 140.000000000000000000
    object ListBoxItem1: TListBoxItem
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'MenuItem 0'
      OnClick = ListBoxItem1Click
    end
    object ListBoxItem2: TListBoxItem
      Position.Y = 19.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 1
      Text = 'MenuItem 1'
    end
    object ListBoxItem3: TListBoxItem
      Position.Y = 38.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 2
      Text = 'MenuItem 2'
    end
  end
  object TabControl1: TTabControl
    Align = Client // also tried Contents
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 434.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabIndex = 1
    TabOrder = 4
    TabPosition = PlatformDefault
    Sizes = (
      640s
      408s
      640s
      408s)
    object TabItem1: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      TextSettings.Trimming = None
      IsSelected = False
      Size.Width = 69.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = ''
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'TabItem1'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 86.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 30.000000000000000000
    end


[EDIT 0]: Added not-working code
[Edit 1]: Clarification of tested values of the Align property

Please show what code you have tried. This kind of thing is relatively trivial to do with a TListBox, TLayout or TRectangle using an animation to "slide out" like it does in WhatsApp

Absolutely yes. I'm pretty sure there is just a little tweak missing. Added the Delphi code, also the head of the .fmx file showing the toolbar with the button, the TTabControl containing the different activities and the TListBox.

It's the alignment of the controls you have. Since TabControl1 is aligned to Client and the ListBoxMenu is aligned Right, of course when it becomes visible it will affect TabControl1. Changing the alignment of TabControl1 to Contents should alleviate that, but that's without setting up a test project myself, so I may have missed something that might also affect it

The cause for your behaviour is the fact that you set your ListBoxMenu.Align property to Right.
This as you have already noted will cause all other controls that rely on automatic alignment to realign their position in order to fit your ListBoxMenu on their right side.
So in order to avoid this behaviour you should change Align property of your ListBoxMenu to None.
This does mean you will probably have to set the initial size and position of your ListBoxMenu from code.

Unfortunately, that does not work. On Windows (DevEnv) there is the Z-order problem mentioned (not clearly by me) above. It means I can see just a few px of the top menu item. On Android, interestingly, simply nothing happens when I change the Align property. The menu is not shown at all.

So why don't you then fix the Z-order of your ListBoxMenu ?  Right clicking on your ListBoxMenu  at design time and choosing Control->BringToFront from the context menu should make sure your ListBoxMenu  has topmost Z-order of all components that share same parent (Form in your case).

The only problem you may encounter is if you are using OS native controls like TMeiaPlayer or TWebBrowser. But that is limitation of how FMX works. You see native are not rendered by FMX framework but instead by OS on top of your FMX content. This is why you can't draw anything on top of such controls.

So I finally got it working on Android and Win64. Here are my changes taken from SiverWarrior and Dave.

TabControl: Align:=TLayoutAlign.Client
ListboxMenu: Align:=TLayoutAlign.None
ListboxMenu: BringToFront on the control, not in the Object Inspector
Main: GlobalUseSkia:=True

The last tweaks have been to use Skia, otherwise the tab's slants are drawn over the menu. Also I had to choose "BringToFront" on the TListBox on the form. It did not work at structure view of the object inspector as the "BringToFront" menu option of the context menu is disabled there. Thank you!
